# fetch data from database order by metabox value (wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display `clinic` post type in WordPress ordered by `clinic_price` (`clinic_price` is a metabox for clinics post type). How can I use `wpdb` to order clinics by price ASC and DESC?

I'm using `WP_Query` to sort posts by price but it only displays one of the clinics!!!

```
$service_meta_price = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($post->post_title) . ' price');

$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'clinics',
    'meta_key' => $service_meta_price,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$clinics = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'meta_key' => $service_meta_price` be `'meta_key' => 'clinic_price'` instead then?

Comment: That meta_key is definitely not good. That's same metabox field for all clinics, right?

Comment: Clinic_price value dosnt same for all clinics

Comment: Each clinic can have its own `clinic_price` meta field with its own value. It seems to me that you're confused about how all this works. Please edit your question to include the code where you register & save your meta field so we can check it out.

Comment: i asking my question in another way
how can join wp_posts with wp_postmeta fields where wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id ?
i just want access to clinic_price in wp_postmeta for ordering clinics

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :

```
$service_meta_price = str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($post->post_title) . ' 
$clinics = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * from wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1 on m1.post_id = wp_posts.ID AND m1.meta_key = $service_meta_price WHERE post_type = "clinics" OR post_type = "surgeons" ORDER BY meta_value DESC');
```

for those who have the same problem
thank you everyone